# mapdist query limit reached in my R session. any solution?

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I have been trying to calculate driving distances from a specific zip code to all other zip codes in a state. The program was running fine until the following error occured:

```
> mapdist('19111 USA', '19187 USA')
by using this function you are agreeing to the terms at :
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=19111+USA&destinations=19187+USA&mode=driving&sensor=false
matching was not perfect, returning what was found.
Error in `*tmp*`[[c(1, 1)]] : no such index at level 1
```

When I run the function distQueryCheck() it indicates that I still have over 2000 queries left.  Am I over the limit despite what the results of distQueryCheck() are?  I suspect that I may be since I have been running this function over the last couple of days.  Are there any ways to increase the limit?  How long do I have to wait until the limit resets back to 2500?

Comment: the limit resets every day, and to increase the limit you can pay for a premium api key

Comment: You can track your quota if you get a (free) API key and using it in `google_distance()` as per [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49224255/5977215)